# Normalizing data to [-1, 1] range

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a training dataset which is of size NxD and a test dataset which is of size AxD. The rows are the data points and the columns are the features.

Now I would like to transform each feature (column) to be in the range [-1, 1]. Moreover, the scaling of the features in the test set should be done with the parameters estimated on the training set. For example, if I do the standardization by subtracting the mean and dividing the standard deviation, I would calculate the mean and standard deviation on the training set and use them to standardize the test set. The same I want to do now for scaling to the range [-1, 1].

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
mins = min(trainingDataset);
maxs = max(trainingDataset);
testDataset = 2*bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus,testDataset,mins), maxs-mins)-1;
```

Comment: Something seems not to work. If I create trainingDataset = rand(5,5) and then I use your function to scale the trainingDataset to [-1,1] then entries with different values are mapped to -1 and 1 respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying the problem is, which may indicate that I misunderstood what you were wanting. What I thought you wanted: each column in `testDataset` (representing the values of one feature across multiple data points) to be normalized in such a way that the min and max values of the corresponding column in `trainingDataset` become -1 and +1.

Comment: So what my code is intended to do (it might of course have a bug) is: first compute the min and max values of the columns in `trainingDataset` (that's what the first two lines do; they should give two row vectors, with one entry in each per feature). Then take `testDataset`, subtract the mins from each columns (that's the inner `bsxfun` call), divide each column by the appropriate `max-min` (that's the outer `bsxfun` call) -- so far we're mapping the extreme values of `testDataset` to [0,1] -- and then transform that by x->2x-1 to get [-1,+1] instead.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. Sorry for the confusion. I did not look at the column but at the complete matrix.

Comment: That's a relief! Glad to be of service.